# How to get iTunes Library top 10 song by playcount within recent 5days?

Tags: ios, itunes, mpmediaitem, mpmediaquery

I'm trying to fetch iTunes library in ios.
And trying to retrieve top 10 playcount song in 5days.

Could you tell me how to do? Here's my code.
MPMediaPropertyPredicate is not right answer...I guess.

```
MPMediaQuery *everything = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];
NSLog(@"Logging items from a generic query...");
NSArray *itemsFromGenericQuery = [everything items];
for (MPMediaItem *song in itemsFromGenericQuery) {
    NSString *songTitle = [song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
    NSString *artistName = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
    NSString *lastPlayeddate = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyLastPlayedDate];
    NSString *playCount = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPlayCount];

    NSLog (@"%@", songTitle);
    text.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@ %@ %@ %@", text.text, songTitle, artistName, lastPlayeddate, playCount];
}
```

All the best.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, play count is considered a "user defined" key, and therefore cannot be used in `MPMediaPropertyPredicate`

See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaItem_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008211-CH1-SW38

You will have to iterate the songs and retrieve these properties manually.

`enumerateValuesForProperties:usingBlock:` is probably your most efficient option here.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaEntity_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MPMediaEntity/enumerateValuesForProperties:usingBlock: